How do I tell mypy that except() will bail a pytest test?
The following code works, but I fell like I shouldn't have to write it:
def test_transaction(self, the_client):
        [...]
        transaction: Transaction = transactions.filter([...]).first()

        # NOTE: this is stupid and unnecessary just to satisfy mypy. 
        #       the next expect() will bail if this test is true, 
        #       so this if statement is completely superfluous
        if transaction is None:
            raise AssertionError("missing transaction")
        
        # I want to tell mypy this works like the above if statement
        expect(transaction).not_to(be_none())  

        # if the if statement above isn't there, it tells me 
        #     None | Transaction doesn't have the property "client"
        expect(transaction.client).to(equal(the_client))
        [...]

Is there an easier way to do this that will satisy mypy? I have 1000+ tests like this and I don't want to add 2000+ more lines of completely unnecessary, useless code just to make a freaking code checker happy.
I have the django and drf stubs installed.

Your best bet is to not run Mypy on test files. Test code rarely needs to be type checked anyway.

This doesn't look right. If you have transaction: Transaction, then mypy should not expect you to write if transaction is None. Do you mean, transaction: Transaction | None = ...?

I don't think you can declare this behavior in the type alone; you would need a mypy plugin to handle expect and code that follows a call to expect specially.

As it is, mypy is hard-coded to recognize that the raise prevents the following code from being reached, so the assumed type of transaction should be Transaction. It's not hard-coded to know that if expect doesn't raise that the argument to expect is similarly narrowed.
